# Apply new cell value in Excel without pressing Enter or moving focus

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm doing a lot of cell value testing in Excel. When I enter to apply the new value, the focus changes from that cell to the cell under it, so I have to return to the cell the change/apply again and again.

Is there a key in the keyboard to apply changes without quitting the cell?

Is there a setting in Excel to apply changes while editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will apply changes but leave you in the same cell. No messing with the settings necessary.

Comment: This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Excel has an option to stop selecting a different cell when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Choose "Options" from the File Menu, then click Advanced and uncheck "After pressing Enter, move selection" Then click "OK".

[image]